# Is there a way to get context inside getters?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I'm using  [flutter_localizations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) to internationalize my app. So i have this class

```
final Article article;
ArticleViewModel({required this.article});

String get name {
 return article.name;
}

String get isGood {
 return article.isGoods ? 'Goods' : 'Services';
}
}
```

Inside the isGood getter, i need to return "Goods" or "Services" translated depending on the language
but i don't have the context to call `Applocalization.of(context)`
I need a good approach to achieve this wihthout passing a BuildContext as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can try my approach, I have used this way for many of my apps. My way is inject `BuildContext` to a singleton class with [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it), like this:

```
@singleton
class AppContext {
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  BuildContext get navigatorContext => navigatorKey.currentState!.context;
}
```

then at your first time your app run, put the injected navigatorKey to `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: getIt<AppContext>().navigatorKey,
)
```

Then, you can get `BuildContext` after that everywhere with:

```
getIt<AppContext>().navigatorContext
```

Comment: Works fine! But where does the @singleton decorator comes from? I did withour it, and i had to register with ```getIt.registerSingleton<AppContext>(AppContext());```  inside the main before runApp();

Comment: Aw yes, I forgot @singleton is the part of https://pub.dev/packages/injectable, which is code generator for get_it. You can register by yourself like you say but if you too lazy like me, you can use injectable xD

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a BuildContext to your ViewModel (like you did with article) and call Applocalization.of(context) inside your getter

Comment: I edited my post. I forgot to mention without passing BuildContext as a parameter.